# Angularjs $http not working if data too long

Tags: angularjs

I am try to use `$http` to submit the form to backend and it is working fine at the beginning.

```
$http({
    method : "POST",
    url    : "handleformurl",
    params : [{user:"Peter",age:"25",gender:"m"},{user:"Chris",age:"23",gender:"m"}]
})
```

Server side can receive all the data without any problem. However, error occurred when I try yo submit the huge form with the same format

```
$http({
    method : "POST",
    url    : "handleformurl",
    params : [{user:"Peter",age:"25",gender:"m"}, + over 2000 user info in the list]
})
```

The total length of `params` is over 200000 characters and I found that server side can't receive anything. Then I try to check the response of `$http` but only limited information is provided

```
"data":null,"status":-1,"statusText":"","xhrStatus":"error"
```

I can't locate the root cause now but it seems there is a limitation for the length. Is that any configuration or setting that can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an **object** to pass, for example:

```
var userInfo = { 
  user: "Peter", 
  age:"25",
  gender:"m"
  ...
}
```

Then, you can pass this object in the Post:

```
$http({ method: "POST", url: handleformurl, data: userInfo });
```

Comment: It's solved now and the main points are : 

1. change the type from string to object and
2. change the "params" to "data"

Thank you very much

Comment: @barry you’re welcome. Consider upvoting if it helped.

Comment: I try but my reputation is too low for casting a vote....